# Compound command in one line in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting different results for both - I'm wondering how both the below commands are different. Can someone please explain ?

`data['Sales_dummy'][data['sales']>=data['sales'].median()]=1`

OR

`data[data['sales']>=data['sales'].median()]['Sales_dummy']=1`

Comment: You're asking about the difference between `data['Sales_dummy'][...] = 1` and `data[...]['Sales_dummy'] = 1`? The pseudo-boolean expression used as one of the indices isn't really relevant.

Comment: The difference is in the memory layout and in the first one you are probably getting a view instead of a copy so the assignment works. This is chained indexing and is the main reason behind the infamous [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas). Use `loc`: `data.loc[data['sales'] >= data['sales'].median(), 'Sales_dummy'] = 1`

Answer (score -1):

`data` is indexed with two different values in the two assignments; the first with `'Sales_dummy'`, the second with the expression `[data['sales']>=data['sales'].median()]`.

In general, indexing of nested data structures is not commutative: `d[x][y]` and `d[y][x]` do not have the same value.